# How to get a csv list from JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have the following sql query and would like to use it with `JdbcTemplate` from spring:

```
    String sql = "SELECT name, age FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE age >= ?";
    List<Employee> employees = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, 18, new EmployeeRowMapper());

    public class EmployeeRowMapper implements RowMapper<Employee> {
      @Override
      public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        employee.setAge(rs.getString("age"));
        return employee;
      }
    }
```

Problem: what if I only care for the output that I'd be given if I execute the sql in any common sql tool? There the output would be:

```
name;age
john;18
doh;22
...
```

As I know my sql, I know that I'd be getting back 2 columns, where the first is the name and then second is the age. So for me it's unnecessairy to extract the data by explicit using the column name, like `rs.getString("age")`?

How can I use `JdbcTemplate` to just output the results as a csv list, without having to map it to objects?

Answer (score 1):

```
String sql = "SELECT name || ';' || age FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE age >= ?";
List<String> employees = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, String.class, 18);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        ResultSetExtractor rse = new ResultSetExtractor() {
            @Override
            public String extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                        sb.append(rs.getObject(i));
                    }
                    sb.append("\n");
                }

                return sb.toString();
            }
        };

 jdbcTemplate.query(sql, 18, rse);
```